# A matrix which has columns with length $1$ has absolute value determinant less or equal to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that if a matrix has columns with lenght $1$ then its determinant has absolute value at most $1$? Can someone give me hint to prove this?

Comment: Does a matrix need to be square to have a determinant?

Comment: @Henry I think he means each column is a normal vector.

Comment: @Henry Yes, here the matrix is square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Hadamard's inequality which says that if $v_i$ are the columns of the $n\times n$ matrix $N$ (with complex entries) then
$$
|\det(N)|\leq \prod_{i=1}^n|v_i|
$$

For a proof see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality).

Comment: Really I need the answer of this question to prove Hadamard's inequality!

Comment: @GhD The proof of Hadamard's inequality provides a complete answer to the question. I am not sure what you meant in your comment.

Comment: You are right. and your answer is also right. I mean if I prove my question then I can prove Hadamard's inequality. I'm looking to an answer to the question to complete the proof of Hadamard's inequality

Comment: @GhD See the link mentioned in my answer. It includes a complete answer to your question.